# Processing collection one by one

Tags: wpf, collections, grid

I have a collection called MessagesCollection. The problem is, when I'm trying to display it using this code:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid Margin="10, 10,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <ListView x:Name="ListMessages" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesCollection}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                    <ListView.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Public\Images\chat_green-textarea.png"/>
                    </ListView.Background>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row ="1">
                <Image Source="Public\Images\chat_green-textarea-tail.png" Height="20" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,-4,0,0"/>
            </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row ="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Foreground="white" FontSize="12">Sent by</Label>

            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <ListView x:Name="ListMessages2" Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesCollection}" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyHeaderStyle}">
                            <GridViewColumn Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The display is like this. [image]

What I want is like this:
Message
 
Sender

In each data in the collection. I know the way I display it is the problem. But I don't really know how to do it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a DataTemplate for the Item in the ListView. The way you are doing is not correct. You don't have to define the ListView twice. Instead bind it once and style DataTemplate according to your needs. An example code close to what you might start on is given below. Style the DataTemplate with whatever content you wish.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>           
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have used GridView here. A flat list with proper data template will help you,

```
<ListView x:Name="ListMessages" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesCollection}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Sorry @XAML Lover, we almost posted the answer simultaneously

Comment: I got an XamlParseException on the closing tag of the stackpanel. I'm new at WPF. SOrry.

Comment: 'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.'